# Controlling camera hardware in Android phone

Tags: android, camera

I want to control the aperture, shutter speed and ISO on my android phone. Is there a way in which I can access the hardware features?

Answer (score 7):

I won't say it's *impossible* to do this, but it IS effectively impossible to do it in a way that's generalizable to all -- or even *many* -- Android phones. If you stray from the official path defined by the Android API, you're pretty much on your own, and this is basically an embedded hardware development project.

Let's start with the basics: you need a schematic of the camera subsystem and datasheets for everything in the image pipeline. For every phone you intend to support. In some cases, you might find a few phones with more or less identical camera subsystems (particularly when you're talking about slightly-different carrier-specific models sold in the US), and occasionally you might get lucky enough to have a lot of similarity between the phone you care about and a Nexus phone.

This is no small feat. As far as I know, not even NEXUS phones have official schematics released. Popular phones (especially Samsung and HTC) usually get teardowns published, so everyone knows the broad details (camera module, video-encoding chipset, etc), but there's still a lot of guesswork involved in figuring out how it's all wired together.

Make no mistake -- this isn't casual hacking territory. If terms like I2C, SPI, MMC, and iDCT mean nothing to you, you aren't likely to get very far. If you don't literally understand how CMOS image sensors are read serially, and how bayer arrays are used to produce RGB images, you're almost certainly in over your head.

That doesn't mean you should throw in the towel and give up... but it DOES mean that trying to hack the camera on a commercial Android phone probably isn't the best place to start. There's a lot of background knowledge you're going to need in order to pull off a project like this, and you really need to acquire that knowledge from a hardware platform that YOU control & have proper documentation for. Make no mistake... on the hierarchy of "hard" Android software projects, this ranks pretty close to the top of the list.

My suggestion (simplified and condensed a bit): buy a Raspberry Pi, and learn how to light up a LED from a GPIO pin. Then learn how to selectively light up 8 LEDs through an 74HC595 shift register. Then buy a SPI-addressed flash chip on a breakout board, and learn how to write to it. At some point, buy a video image sensor with "serial" (fyi, "serial" != "rs232") interface from somebody like Sparkfun.com & learn how to read it one frame at a time, and dump the raw RGB data to flash. Learn how to use i2c to read and write the camera's control registers. At this point, you MIGHT be ready to tackle the camera in an Android phone for single photos.

If you're determined to start with an Android phone, at least stick to "Nexus" devices for now, and don't buy the phone (if you don't already own it) until you have the schematics, datasheets, and sourcecode in your possession. Don't buy the phone thinking you'll be able to trace the schematic yourself. You won't. At least, not unless you're a grad student and have one hell of a graduate-level electronics lab (with X-Ray capabilities) at your disposal. Most of these chips and modules are micro-BGA. You aren't going to trace them with a multimeter, and every Android camera I'm aware of has most of its low-level driver logic hidden in loadable kernel modules whose source isn't available.

That said, I'd dearly love to see somebody pull a project like this off. :-)

Comment: Is there any way to at least "hook" into somewhere at the driver level to determine when the hardware camera takes a photo?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Somewhere in the gigabytes of sourcecode for CM10.1, you might be able to find the source to either the 'camera' app or the abstraction-layer it interacts with. It's possible that an event fires somewhere when a picture gets taken & you could probably find it somewhere in there... if you can find the source file to begin with. Maybe try running a program like CatLog as root, start saving the log output, take a pic, stop capturing the log, then hunt through the log looking for a clue about the camera app's package name.

Answer (score 3):

Android has published online training which contain all the information you need:
[You can find it here - Media APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

However, there are limitations, not all hardware's support all kind of parameters.
And if I recall correctly, you can't control the shutter speed and ISO.